# with illness following a period

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

> She has been diagnosed with illness **following** a period of
>   self-isolation and subsequent testing.

in this sentence is (following) means (after a period) or (coming a period) ?

Answer (score 0):

**Following** means **after**. (You have only to google it!)

Note that we don't speak of being **diagnosed with (an) illness**. The whole point of diagnosis is to establish, not that somebody is ill, but what exactly illness they are suffering from.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diagnosis